# Как указать максимальное соотношение сторон Canvas в Unity

Tags: unity3d, webgl, яндекс-игры

Я делаю игру в Unity под WebGl для яндекс игр. Мою игру не приняли так-как соотношение сторон не должно превышать 1:2. Помогите пожалуйста с этой проблемой. Настройки нужно менять в Unity или в файле index.html? И как?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.